# Python: Best Practice - Abstract Parent and MixIn-Classes - How to handle attributes that are only defined in child classes

Tags: python, inheritance

I am in a situation where I have multiple classes that inherit from a common parent class that provides certain shared methods. The parent class by itself is not meaningful - no objects of this class should be instantiated. The shared methods will access attributes that are only defined in the classes that inherit from it.

What is the best way to handle such situation? (And also make PyCharm stop complaining about undefined attributes.)

Below an example to clarify the situation that I am thinking of:

```
class DataLoader:

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data.loc[:, self.output_columns]

    def get_meta_data(self):
        meta_data_columns = [col for col in self.data.columns if col not in self.output_columns]
        return self.data.loc[:, meta_data_columns]

class ZodiacSignLoader(DataLoader):
    output_columns = ["name", "zodiac sign"]
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = self._load_data()

    def _load_data(self):
        # some loading procedure for some data
        # e.g. with columns ["name", "date of birth", "place of birth", "nationality"]


class OccupationLoader(DataLoader):
    output_columns = ["name", "occupation"]
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = self._load_data()

    def _load_data(self):
        # some loading procedure for some different data,
        # e.g. with columns ["name", "occupation", "university", "date of birth", "nationality"]
```

The intention of the above example is the following: I have several classes that load data from a Database and compute certain features - these are delivered by `get_data()`. However, since the database is quite unstable I want to be able to create a report consisting of the input on which the computation of the features is based in order to support validation if anything goes wrong. This data shall be provided by `get_metadata()`.

Since I have several classes of this kind, I want to move the interface methods `get_data()` and `get_metadata()` to a parent class - these methods must however access the attributes `data` and `output_columns`, which are not defined in the parent class.

I faced similar situations also when I created MixIn Classes - that sometimes had to access attributes that were only defined for functions that inherit the Mixin.

Comment: Consider using an abstract base class https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractproperty

Comment: Looks like `abc.abstractproperty` is deprecated. You can use `abc.abstractmethod` to make an abstract property instead. https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod